# Как сделать паузу в любом месте кода на js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пишу небольшой userscript на js для онлайн игры, небольшая автоматизация рутинных действий (бот). 
Возникла необходимость делать задержки в любом месте кода после выполнения какого либо действия.
Например что то на подобии delay() в делфи, паскале.. Останавливает выполнение программы на заданное в параметре количество миллисекунд (1000 миллисекунд в 1 секунде).

Мб кто то сталкивался с подобной задачей мб писал подобную функцию задержки.
setTimeout и setInterval не подходят как то сильно загромождают код если пос тоянно их вставлять и начинаешь путаться со временем а вот функция delay() в любом месте кода была бы идеальна. Мб есть какие то библиотеки сторонние для решения подобных задач?

Comment: Решение на enSO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep

Comment: setTimeout единственный вариант. Если есть какие-то библиотеки - то это просто обертки над setTimeout

Comment: @Darth Спасибо, то что надо!

Answer (score 3):

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function demo() {
  console.log('Taking a break...');
  await sleep(2000);
  console.log('Two second later');
}

demo();
```